# handle autocomplete with watin

Tags: c#, ajax, autocomplete, popup, watin

Im working with a textfield where when i write in it, then appear an autocomplete list where i can choose an element.

The problem is that i cant select any one from these autocomplete list with watin, and because this, i can continue with the test.

How can i handle that? Im trying with this:

```
 browser.TextField(Find.ByName("ctl00$cpContent$txtCustomerPA")).TypeText("ca");
        string cliente = "115001-CAJA ESPAÑA SSCC EL PORTILLO";
        Element list = browser.Element(Find.ByText(cliente));

        list.MouseDown();
```

With that i can select the element of the list, but i cant choose it for the textfield... Help pls! How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

try to set value of the element not type it.

try something similar to this "check the syntax":

```
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("BLAHBLAHBLAHB")).SetAttributeValue("value","ca");
```

Instead of Value because its a list check the html and see what the call the option it could be called "Country" or state???

```
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("BLAHBLAHBLAHB")).SetAttributeValue("state","ca");
```

;)

Hope this helps mate,
Good Luck

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

Try using `list.Click();` instead of mousedown.